# How to retrieve all pending and active tasks with celery

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to retrieve all currently `pending` and `active` tasks from Celery.

`active`, `scheduled` and `reserved` are simple to obtain:

```
i = celery_app.control.inspect()
tasks=list()
for k in i.active():
    tasks += i.active()[k]
for k in i.reserved():
    tasks += i.reserved()[k]
for k in i.scheduled():
    tasks += i.scheduled()[k]
```

However, this does not include tasks that have not been `scheduled` or `reserved` yet.  The following code retrieves these tasks, but obviously only works with Redis, assumes a JSON serialization, and it's not ideal for a variety of reasons.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(
        host='localhost',
        port='6379',
    )
tasks = [json.loads(pending_task)['headers'] for pending_task in r.lrange('celery', 0, -1)]
```

Is there a way to retrieve these `pending` tasks in a form similar to `inspect.active()` with easy access to `args`, `kwargs`, `id` (preferably through Celery, so I do not need to specify the Celery backend and serialization, etc)?

EDIT (hedging my bet)

From what I can tell this is not simple, and there is no `i.pending()` in celery.  So, I have a few sub questions which will allow me to write this myself.

1. How to get a list of active celery queues? (the above assumes default queue only) Perhaps something like `queues = [q['exchange']['name'] for host in i.active_queues().values() for q in host])`
2. How to *generically* get messages in those queues?  This would be a generic version of `r.lrange('celery', 0, -1)` above.
3. <strike>How to *generically* decode/de-serialize messages? This would be a generic version of `json.loads(...) above`</strike>
   `celery_app.backend.decode`

With that info it should be straightforward to pull the necessary information from the message headers.